# Configuring a conda environment in PyCharm, i can't find conda execute in bin

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, execute, bin

For configuring a conda environment in PyCharm, In: (https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/pycharm/)  it is said, for  conda execute , go to location: `User/../anaconda3/bin/conda`.
but I can not find Conda there. So why?

my bin folder:
[image]

I downloaded the new version of Anaconda from its site and reinstalled Anaconda several times.
I have a conda execute in script folder, can i copy and paste it in bin folder?

[image]

Comment: Could you provide more information?

Comment: i aded a image of my bin folder

Comment: From [this](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/) page: "Select an install for “Just Me” unless you’re installing for all users (which requires Windows Administrator privileges)", so I guess you are installing for all user?

Comment: No I installed it for a user. "Just Me"

Comment: Hmm. Sound strange.

Comment: I have a conda execute in script folder, in your idea can i copy and paste it in bin folder?

Comment: Like what? Can you show the picture?

Comment: Yes, I added it in question.

Comment: Try if that path work, don't copy to the bin.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is that you should probably use the Conda exe file inside the script folder.